# How can I monitor the tasks started with pyspark

Tags: pyspark, spark-ui

I am using pyspark to run some tasks on a cluster.
I want to see the status of the tasks.
I think that the UI must be started by default
[as mentioned here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-webui.html?q=).

But I am unable to get UI (http://localhost:4040 or so).

Comment: Are you using a YARN or something?

Comment: No. I am not using YARN